# Does "Messages in iCloud" include SMS?

Tags: icloud, messages, sms

The page on [Messages in iCloud](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208532) mentions keeping "all your messages" on iCloud. It then goes on to activate the functionality on the *iMessage* settings tab in macOS.

- Does it apply to SMS messages?
- Does it only apply to SMS messages under certain conditions, e.g. only after enabling receiving SMS on another device?

Comment: Macs can't send or receive SMS messages. They all have to go through a phone. Messages can make that appear seamless

Comment: @mmmmmm Yes, but how does that relate to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messages in iCloud applies to all SMS. The service can both be used to backup messages in iCloud and sync them across all your devices.

While it may be confusing to manage a SMS service setting under iMessage settings, it still applies to all your SMS if they have been synced from your iPhone. Mac cannot send or receive regular SMS themselves because they don't have the hardware required.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have a reference or do you know this from personal experience? Although tangential, I would argue that it is not a backup service for the very reason that it is a two way sync (according to the linked documentation).

Comment: Personal experience. According to this page https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207428 iCloud Backup for an iOS device skips backing up content that is already in iCloud and gives messages as an example (note 2 in link above), that's made me think it is a backup service. I'll update the answer to reflect your feedback.

Comment: Ah yes, like all other iCloud synced data it is excluded from backups and therefore vulnerable to user and programming error. I have to say I'm moderately worried about e.g. my notes because of this fact — if I, or the app, make a mistake there's no way to reverse it unless I just happen to sync it to a Mac with time machine turned on.